# VBA Excel Launching Word Doc can't create clickable checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, ms-word, clickable

I have an Excel Document, where I am looping through the cells to generate a word document with clickable check boxes. I am taking 1 cell value as the header, the next column cell value as the value that needs a check box next to it. Basically it is a list of tasks I want to cut and paste in email to ensure they have been completed. I am using late binding to generate the word document from Excel and am wondering if that has something to do with my issues. I have tried all different examples of creating the checkboxes and usually get an Object Required error message.

```
Dim wrdApp As Object 

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

Set objSelection = wrdApp.Selection

    For Row = 2 to lRow

       objSelection.TypeText Chr(13) & Cells(Row, 1).Value & Chr(13)

       'Here is where I would like to write a checkbox so it is to the left of the column 2 value

       objSelection.TypeText Cells(Row, 2).Value)

    Next Row
```

I have never written from Excel to Word before, it seems like I should be able to have a simple one line of code of writing the checkbox in place but maybe I am wrong.

I recorded a macro of adding a check box and when I try this code:

```
 Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox
```

I get

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

When I try going along these lines:

```
   wrdDoc.Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=InsertAfter, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox
```

I get

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Trying something like this

```
Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox
```

I get

> Wrong Number of Arguments or invalid property assignment.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the fact that both Excel and Word have `Selection` objects and Excel is automatically assuming an Excel selection is meant. Since Excel doesn't have form fields, you get the error. Use `wrdApp.Selection.FormFields.Add` and see if that helps.

Comment: wrdApp.Selection.FormFields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox gives me Wrong Number of Arguments or invalid property assignment. Removing the range also gives me the same error. I have never written anything for Word before so I am really not sure how a line of code like this should look.

Comment: Did you put `wrdApp` in front of *both* `Selection`? AND if you're using late-binding you can't use `wdFieldFormCheckBox` - you need the Long data type equivalent. You can query that in Word's VBA Editor or look it up in the Help.

Comment: Yes I took out objSelection references and replaced all with wrdApp.Selection, and using this for the checkboxes will compile and run (I pulled it out of macro record in WORD where it did give me a checkbox), it is just not giving me checkboxes, it is putting boxes around all the text with 3 dots on the left. wrdApp.Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)

Comment: Well, now you've changed what you're trying to do. Your original quesetion is about using form fields. Now you post about content controls. That's something else entirely... You might want to use the [edit] link below the question to bring it up-to-date with your actual situation.

Comment: Didn't really change what I am trying to do,  just trying to see how I can get it to work. I just want a header, below that a clickable checkbox with some text to the right of it. Thanks for your help.